# What does "stockade" mean in Matrix series?

Tags: the-matrix

These are lines from *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003):

> **Captain Roland:** *What happens when you get back to Zion......and the
> commander throws you in **the stockade**?*
>
> **Morpheus:** *He won't.*

What does "stockade" mean in the Matrix series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[Stockade (Noun)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stockade#:%7E:text=US%20a%20military%20prison%20or%20detention%20area)**
>
> US: A military prison or detention area

---

Commander Lock's orders are clear and unambiguous.

> **Niobe:** *We’re gonna do what Commander Lock ordered us to do. We’ll evacuate broadcast level and return to Zion.*

Morpheus, as Senior Captain present, says that he's wanting a ship to remain behind. Roland suggests that because Morpheus is countermanding a direct order from their superior, when he gets back to Zion he's going to get his arse thrown in jail ("the stockade") while he awaits a court martial.

Note that this appears to be [a literal place](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/fb50c26f-2962-4ecb-8fbd-f30c9de8e86d) rather than a figure of speech.